# How do you populate a displaytag column title with a Struts2 properties file entry?

Tags: struts2, displaytag, properties-file

In Struts2 you can populate a label for a component with a value from a properties file.  The properties file must have the same name as the Struts2 Action Class that will serve up the JSP and be in the same folder as that Action Class.

```
<s:textfield key="field.label.casereference" name="caseReference" />
```

I want to do the same thing with a displaytag column.  But it doesn't seem to work.

Columns in displaytag have an attribute called titleKey that is suppose to let you do this.  But it doesn't seem to work.

```
<display:table class="displaytag" id="Table2" name="getResultlistCases" clearStatus="true" requestURI="/AbsHearingSrALJ_homePage.action">
    <display:column style="width:8%;" property="aljNum" titleKey="field.label.aljNumber" />
    <display:column style="width:9%;" property="location" titleKey="field.label.location" />
    <display:column style="width:10%;" property="caseName" titleKey="field.label.caseName" />
    <display:column style="width:25%;" property="scheduledTime" titleKey="field.label.scheduledTime" />
```

The titleKey field is not getting the value from the properties file.  It works when I use the key field of a Struts2 textfield, but not with a column's titleKey field for displaytag.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Displaytag provides an interface I18nResourceProvider with a few ready
>   to use implementations which match the behaviour of common frameworks.
>   This is configured in displaytag.properties using the locale.provider
>   key. By default the JSTL implementation is used.

And in [org.displaytag.localization.I18nJstlAdapter](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/apidocs/index.html?org/displaytag/localization/I18nJstlAdapter.html) description:

> It will make the titleKey attribute of column tag works the same as
>   fmt:message's key property. This tag must be the descendant of a
>   fmt:bundle tag in order to use the titleKey.

So you should use following approach (I tested - it worked):

```
   <fmt:bundle basename="action.HelloWorld">
      <display:table name="test">
         <display:column property="aljNum" titleKey="field.label.aljNumber" />
      </display:table>
   </fmt:bundle>
```

Remember also that "basename" in fmt:bundle is a fully-qualified resource name without ".properties" extension.

Comment: I tried doing what you said and it didn't work. And I set the following properties in displaytag.properties: locale.provider=org.displaytag.localization.I18nJstlAdapter and locale.resolver=org.displaytag.localization.I18nJstlAdapter

Comment: Check the location of your files:  /struts2-test/src/main/java/action/HelloWorld.java  /struts2-test/src/main/java/action/HelloWorld.properties

Comment: If you see "AljNum" then it doesn't find your properties file. If you see "???field.label.aljNumber???" then it finds your properties file, but there is no corresponding key in the properties file.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work.  I had my properties file right, I was just having an issue with JSP caching in my IDE.  Thanks for your help.